# Iterating the output from the script and creating a dictionary

Tags: ansible

Here is my ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: Execute script in remote machine
    script: sysget.sh
    register: output
  - debug:
      var: output.stdout_lines
```

The output:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xx.xx.xx.xx] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": [
        "OS type: Red Hat",
        "Product Version: 1.11.0-2.el7",
        "No of CPU: 4",
        "CPU Clock Freq: 2394.454 MHz",
        "IP-Address:  xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "RAM:  7.6377 GB",
        "Hostname:  dummy",
        "OS Version: CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 (Core)"
    ]
}
```

I want to iterate through this output and create a dictionary of key value pair, something like below:

```
{"OS type":"Red Hat","RAM":"7.6377 GB"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below does the job

```
    - set_fact:
        sysget_dict: "{{ dict(my_keys2|zip(my_vals)) }}"
      vars:
        my_keys: "{{ output.stdout_lines|
                     map('regex_replace','^(.*)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$', '\\1')|
                     list }}"
        my_vals: "{{ output.stdout_lines|
                     map('regex_replace','^(.*)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$', '\\2')|
                     list }}"
        my_keys2: "{{ my_keys|
                      map('regex_replace', '[^_a-zA-Z0-9]', '_')|
                      list }}"
    - debug:
        var: sysget_dict
    - debug:
        var: sysget_dict.OS_type
    - debug:
        var: sysget_dict.RAM
```

give

```
    "sysget_dict": {
        "CPU_Clock_Freq": "2394.454 MHz", 
        "Hostname": "dummy", 
        "IP_Address": "xx.xx.xx.xx", 
        "No_of_CPU": "4", 
        "OS_Version": "CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 (Core)", 
        "OS_type": "Red Hat", 
        "Product_Version": "1.11.0-2.el7", 
        "RAM": "7.6377 GB"
    }
    "sysget_dict.OS_type": "Red Hat"
    "sysget_dict.RAM": "7.6377 GB"
```

---

> Q: *"How do I use this variable "sysget_dict" as an input to the script, which expects dictionary as input?"*

A: Write the variable "sysget_dict" to a file. For example, use `template`

```
shell> cat sysget.json.j2
{{ sysget_dict|to_nice_json }}
```

The task

```
    - template:
        src: sysget.json.j2
        dest: sysget.json
```

gives

```
shell> cat sysget.json 
{
    "CPU_Clock_Freq": "2394.454 MHz",
    "Hostname": "dummy",
    "IP_Address": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "No_of_CPU": "4",
    "OS_Version": "CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 (Core)",
    "OS_type": "Red Hat",
    "Product_Version": "1.11.0-2.el7",
    "RAM": "7.6377 GB"
}
```

It's possible to use this file as an input to a script. For example

```
shell> cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/sh
jq '.' $1
```

gives

```
shell> ./test.sh sysget.json 
{
  "CPU_Clock_Freq": "2394.454 MHz",
  "Hostname": "dummy",
  "IP_Address": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
  "No_of_CPU": "4",
  "OS_Version": "CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 (Core)",
  "OS_type": "Red Hat",
  "Product_Version": "1.11.0-2.el7",
  "RAM": "7.6377 GB"
}
```

Comment: :How do i use this variable "sysget_dict" as an input to the script, which expects dictionary as input?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example. If you have issues open a new question.